# Exclude a pattern from code coverage?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

As far as I understand one can exclude files and directories from code coverage *by name* but is it possible to exclude by matching a pattern ?

I ask this because I don't want to mention the path to all my `view` sub-folders one by one in my `phpunit.xml`. Something like `<exclude>*/view</exclude>` perhaps ? By this I mean "exclude all `view` folders wherever you reach them".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can specify file patterns to exclude from Code Coverage.  Here is a sample of one of my PHPUnit.xml.dist files.

```
<!-- Add files not covered with tests into Code Coverage Analysis -->
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".class">.</directory>
        <directory suffix=".fn">.</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>ExternalLibraries</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

The [PHPUnit Manual for Code Coverage](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) and then the [Including/Excluding files](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.blacklist-whitelist) for Code Coverage sections of the manual will show you additional options to specify the file patterns by directory or name.

Comment: -1: This answer was not helpful, it only lead to the next question of the same user which lead to a further comment based on your suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18955271/367456

Comment: +1 to counter "hakre".  This answer looks pretty reasonable to me.